# PHP TCPdf prevent page break if content overflows

Tags: tcpdf

Is there any way to prevent page break when the contents overflows?

I want to hide the overflowed contents rather than creating new page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn automatic page breaking off using the `TCPDF::SetAutoPageBreak()` method:

from documentation:

> SetAutoPageBreak( $auto, $margin = 0 )
>
> Enables or disables the automatic page breaking mode. When enabling,
>   the second parameter is the distance from the bottom of the page that
>   defines the triggering limit. By default, the mode is on and the
>   margin is 2 cm.

https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/